# I am trying to store a value for a variable on window.onload for later use

Tags: javascript, html, css, window, onload

not working. Why? i want to do this because seoquake bar adds dis to my source code and it messes up a for loop i am using that is based on the div length of document

```
window.onload = var dekki = function window(){
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    divLength = div.length;
    return divLength;
}

document.write(dekki);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just separate them then they will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var showDivLength = function () {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    divLength = div.length;
    if (divLength > 0)
        div[divLength-1].innerHTML = divLength;
    return divLength;
}
window.onload = function () {
    showDivLength();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = var dekki = function ...
```

You are assigning a function to 'dekki' here. Instead, do

```
window.onload = function () {
    var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    window.dekki = div.length;
}
```

Comment: Nevermind.  Checking directly after window.load will  give you undefined though, because the function hasn't been called yet.  (Silly mistake.)

Comment: if i document.write(dekki); or document.write(window.dekki); nothing will show up or undefined will show up

Comment: yeah i need to store that div.length number and use it later on. how do i do that?

Comment: At which point do you do that document.write? Obviously, the variable will be defined *after* window.onload is called. If you want to do something right after the page loads, put that into the function too.

Comment: all i want to be able to do is store a variable with the reordered div length after the page loads. the only reason i am using document write is to check to see if the variable is storing the correct number, what i really want to do is use that div length for a for loop later on. So i need the div.length to be passed on to a variable that i can then use later on. This is because sometimes browser addons add divs to the source code

Comment: i am using an external script, do i need to place it within the function i am using it for?

Comment: i need the div.length to be collected after load and then be stored - can anybody help me?

Comment: Isn't it stored? Have you tried to actually use it? Are you sure your code in external script does not run **before** window.onload? Onload only triggers after the page is loaded and all scripts are executed.